# Cómo meter en una tabla campos de otra tabla sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Básicamente estoy haciendo una aplicación con PHP y SQL, SGBD MySQL. El caso es el siguiente: tengo dos tablas:

```
Diccionario auxiliar:

ean char(13)
marca varchar(30)
categoria varchar (500)

Proveedores:

ean char(13)
marca varchar(30)
categoria varchar (500)
```

Evidentemente, cada tabla tiene más campos, pero estoy poniendo sólo los campos que nos interesan. El caso es que quiero:

1-Meter esos campos de proveedores en la tabla diccionario_auxiliar.
2-Controlar que si el ean no existe (el ean es la PK, 13 dígitos) que meta todo el registro y que si existe lo actualice.

El punto 2 no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo y el punto 1 estoy intentando diversas formas pero no estoy siendo capaz. Por ejemplo:

```
"INSERT INTO diccionario_auxiliar (`ean`, `marca`, `categoria`) SELECT `ean`, `marca`, `categoria` FROM proveedores";
```

A ver si alguien tiene idea de cómo puedo hacerlo, porque realmente no estoy encontrando cómo hacerlo. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: En el planteamiento de la pregunta indica si estás *normalizando* datos. Lo digo porque si no es así estamos ante un caso de redundancia de datos porque tienes dos tablas idénticas. Explica por ejemplo por qué los datos tienes que pasar a `diccionario_auxiliar` ¿? Convendría también que des detalles sobre el contexto para entender un poco el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo bastante curiosidad por entender el caso de uso... Normalmente lo que harías sería llenar la tabla auxiliar y hacer referencia a esa tabla y utilizar join's.

Dicho esto, lo que estás buscando es `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO diccionario_auxiliar (`ean`, `marca`, `categoria`) SELECT `ean`, `marca`, `categoria` FROM proveedores p ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE marca=p.marca, categoria=p.categoria;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, este código sí funciona, pero lo estaba ejecutando en el MySQL con las comillas puestas:

```
"INSERT INTO diccionario_auxiliar (`ean`, `marca`, `categoria`) SELECT `ean`, `marca`, `categoria` FROM proveedores";
```

Aquí el único problema lo tengo a la hora de comprobar si el ean ya existe o no, ya que me gustaría hacerlo directamente con SQL (sin tener que recurrir a arrays de PHP, a fin de que el tiempo de ejecución sea menor, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo. Gracias.

Comment: mejor actualiza la pregunta en vez de añadir "respuestas" :D